# Simple scala.swing application fails

Tags: scala

I am using [scalas](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Scripts.html) to run a simple scala.swing application:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scalas

/***         
scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-swing" % "2.1.1"
*/         


import scala.swing._

object FirstSwingApp extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "First Swing App"
    contents = new Button {
      text = "Click me"
    }
  }
}
```

This compiles and runs (on OSX 10.14), but there is no visible output; the process just terminates after a few seconds. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from this documentation https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Scripts.html - `scalas` doesn't work like `java -jar ...`, that is, it isn't running your `main` class in some `object`.

It merely executes code as if it was REPL, so if you want to execute code, run it yourself:

```scala
#!/usr/bin/env scalas

/***         
scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-swing" % "2.1.1"
*/         


import scala.swing._

// creates object but doesn't run anything
object FirstSwingApp extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "First Swing App"
    contents = new Button {
      text = "Click me"
    }
  }
}

FirstSwingApp.main(new Array[String](0)) // run main manually, or whatever you prefer
```